# Under which group conditions is the homomorphism $g_2 f_1 :H_1 \to G\to H_2$ an isomorphism?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, group-isomorphism

Let $G$ be a group and $H_1 ,H_2$ be two r-images of $G$; i.e. there exist two homomorphisms $f_i :H_i \to G$ and $g_i :G\to H_i$ such that $g_i f_i =id_{H_i}$, for $i=1,2$.

**My question**: Under which group conditions is the homomorphism $g_2 f_1 :H_1 \to G\to H_2$ an isomorphism?

Remember that  $H_i$ is an r-image of $G$ iff $G={\rm im}f_i \ltimes {\rm ker}g_i$.

**What I've tried:** For example, I could prove that if ${\rm im}f_1={\rm im}f_2$ and ${\rm im}f_1$ is finite, then $g_2 f_1$ is an isomorphism. Also, I could show that if $G$ is indecomposable in terms of semidirect factors (I mean if $G=H\ltimes N$, then $N=1$ or $N=G$), then $f_1$ and $g_2$ are both isomorphism, which is really strong result because in this situation we have $G\cong H_i$.

I know that an epimorphims between two Hopfian isomorphic groups is an isomorphism but I don't know when $g_2 f_1$ is an epimorphism.

I have to say that I am working on the number of r-images of an arbitrary group up to isomorphism and my question comes from it.

Comment: This question seems to broad to me. I'd be very surprised if there was anything general to be said, instead it seems more likely that the answer varies from group to group. For instance, in the very simplest situation where $G=\mathbb Z^2$ and $H_1,H_2 \approx \mathbb Z$ there is a very simple answer, however the answer is quite specific to this situation.